# Disk Activity Remote Computer - Display activity changes in textbox with -Continuous

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I am developing a dashboard to view a remote computers data (Eventviewer, Files in a directory, running Tasks, etc...). All of these are working and being display with no problems on the Dashboard.

The issue I have is when I click a Command button it runs the code shown below and it displays the Disk activity for the logical disk **C:** of a remote computer in the textbox **txtDiskActivity.Text** on the dashboard but only one line is shown (view Image).

[Disk Activity Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJfpV.jpg)

```
txtDiskActivity.Text = RunScript("Get-WmiObject -computername LT-WIN1064 -NameSpace root\\CIMV2 -Class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk | where name -eq C: | select AvgDisksecPerWrite, name");
```

What I am trying to do is to keep this code running so it can keep showing the disk activity changes for the LogicalDisk until I exit out of the dashboard.

I have tried using **-Continuous** and **-SampleInterval** **2 -MaxSamples** 10 but I cant get it to work.

One condition is that I will need to be able to use the other controls on dashboard while this code this is running.

Any suggestion?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I as able to resolve my issue by using a **TIMER** suggested by Sabah Shariq @

[Get Disk Counter Write activity code for remote computer and keep it refreshing.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/423e188d-fe3f-4fae-a7d0-f666834c4c4e/get-disk-counter-write-activity-code-for-remote-computer-and-keep-it-refreshing?forum=csharpgeneral)

I added a Timer to the form and then I added the following code to the timer:

```
txtDiskActivity.Text = FunctionCall("Get-WmiObject -computername LT-WIN1064 -NameSpace root\\CIMV2 -Class Win32_PerfRawData_PerfDisk_LogicalDisk | where name -eq C: | select AvgDisksecPerWrite, name");
```

I then added the following code to the Click Button:

```
 tmrDiskActivity.Interval = 1000;
 tmrDiskActivity.Start();
```

When I click the button it starts to show the activity of the disk in the textbox and best of all, it doesn't hang my dashboard.

Regards,